# Mysql query with optional where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, select, isnull

I have a form which is used to search the database. The form consists of four fields, including two date fields: (Col1, Col2, Datefm, DateTo). Users have the option to fill the values in these fields. They may fill the value in one field or two field or three field or all fields. Based on these values my query has to search the database.

I made a query which fetches the data, but it works only when all the values in the fields are available. I want it to exclude the where conditions which are not filled by the user. How can i achieve that?

I tried the following code.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE tcol1=$col1
    AND tcol2=$col2
    AND tDateto=$Dateto
    AND tdatefm=$Datefm
```

Comment: have your code make different queries depending which form fields are provided

Comment: No only these four field  but it depends on the user .Suppose user fill the value in Col1 than the query will search the data  like this query " select * from table1 where tcol1=col1." only

Comment: IFNULL function may be helpful for you

Comment: this would be easier to discuss if you actually showed your code, not juse the query it is currently using.  basically, the right way to do this is for your *code* to form a query with the correct where condition based on which form fields were filled out.  there is also a way to do it detecting blank values inside your query itself, but that is a much worse way

Comment: The direct use of placeholders like `tcol1=$col1` scares me. The **FIRST** thing you should do is read up on SQL injection attacks and how to avoid them using your client platform's mechanism for prepared statements/parameterized queries.

Answer (score 2):

As ysth has pointed out in the comments above, you should build your WHERE clause dynamically based on which form fields are populated.

Here's a very simple example which will work for the presented use case (mysqli based as your question was originally tagged with mysqli):

```php
$where = [];
$params = [];

if (isset($_GET['Col1']) && !empty($_GET['Col1'])) {
    $where[] = 'tcol1 = ?';
    $params[] = $_GET['Col1'];
}

if (isset($_GET['Col2']) && !empty($_GET['Col2'])) {
    $where[] = 'tcol2 = ?';
    $params[] = $_GET['Col2'];
}

if (isset($_GET['Datefm']) && !empty($_GET['Datefm'])) {
    $where[] = 'tdatefm = ?';
    $params[] = $_GET['Datefm'];
}

if (isset($_GET['Dateto']) && !empty($_GET['Dateto'])) {
    $where[] = 'tDateto = ?';
    $params[] = $_GET['Dateto'];
}

$whereClause = count($where) ? ' WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where) : '';

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM Table1' . $whereClause);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this OR function. like the one below

```
`SELECT *
 FROM Table1
 WHERE ($col1 IS NULL OR tcol1 = $col1)
 AND ($col2 IS NULL OR tcol2 = $col2)
 AND ($Dateto IS NULL OR tDateto = $Dateto)
 AND ($Datefm IS NULL OR tdatefm = $Datefm);`
```